# Uppercase SQL statements don't work in Snowflake stored procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the example below the `working_one` stored procedure works, while the `broken_one` does not. The only difference between the two is letters case of SQL statement.

```sql
create table tmp (
  raw_json variant
);

-- 2019-01-01 = 1546347600000
-- 2018-01-01 = 1514811600000
insert into tmp select parse_json('{ "timestamp":1514811600000}');

create or replace procedure working_one(TIME_VALUE varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
as
$$
var stmtString = "delete from tmp where to_timestamp(raw_json:timestamp::string) < to_timestamp(:1);"
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: stmtString, binds: [TIME_VALUE]})
var rs = stmt.execute()
rs.next()
return rs.getColumnValue(1)
$$;

create or replace procedure broken_one(TIME_VALUE varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
as
$$
var stmtString = "DELETE FROM TMP WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(RAW_JSON:TIMESTAMP::STRING) < TO_TIMESTAMP(:1);"
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: stmtString, binds: [TIME_VALUE]})
var rs = stmt.execute()
rs.next()
return rs.getColumnValue(1)
$$;

call broken_one('1546347600000');
call working_one('1546347600000');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the problem is in the case-sensitivity of the SQL, or even that it's a Stored Procedure.  The issue is that the attribute inside your JSON is case-sensitive.  Try this and tell me if that works better for you.

```
create or replace procedure fixed_one(TIME_VALUE varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
as
$$
var stmtString = "DELETE FROM TMP WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(RAW_JSON:timestamp::STRING) < TO_TIMESTAMP(:1);"
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: stmtString, binds: [TIME_VALUE]})
var rs = stmt.execute()
rs.next()
return rs.getColumnValue(1)
$$;
```

Comment: I've been bitten by this a lot when writing ad-hoc queries with JSON objects, nice catch.

Comment: Mike, it works! Thanks! 
P.S. Would be nice to add  this information captured in the documentation. Me and Simeon must not be the only people who faced this

Comment: There is a note about this in the documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-query.html.  It probably should be noted more, I agree.  How I think about it is that Snowflake table and columns are not case-sensitive, but the data is.  When querying VARIANT data, that'd mean the attributes are also case-sensitive.  Glad I could help with your issue!